# Compare times in SQLite in hh:min format whit change of name of Day

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a problem with a SQLite query.
My problem is the given table.

> ID / Day / Time
>
> 001 / Mo / 12:23
>
> ...

The point is that a process with id x ends on a day at a certain time.
I'm supposed to determine when the process started. The process takes 1 hour 55 minutes.
My problem is that when the process is finished for example at 0:55 Wednesday, the day must be changed from Wednesday to Tuesday.
To calculate the time, I use the following method:

```
time(Zeit_SE, '-115 minutes')
```

Since the data was given to me, I have no changse to change it, there are about 36,000 pieces.

```
INSERT INTO Ergebniss (id, Tag, Uhrzeit, Zugnummer, Bemerkung, Veraenderung, Anzahl_Sammler)
SELECT id_2, CASE WHEN Zeit_SE > '1:55' THEN VT_SE
                  WHEN ZEIT_SE < '1:55' THEN CASE WHEN VT_SE = 'Mo' THEN VT_SE = 'So' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Di' THEN VT_SE = 'Mo' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Mi' THEN VT_SE = 'Di' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Do' THEN VT_SE = 'Mi' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Fr' THEN VT_SE = 'Do' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Sa' THEN VT_SE = 'Fr' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'So' THEN VT_SE = 'Sa' 
                            END
                  END,
time(Zeit_SE, '-115 minutes'), Zugnummer_Abfahrt, 'Abfahrt Zug', COUNT (Anz_Wagen) * (-1),'0'FROM Wagenuebergaenge 
INNER JOIN Abfahrt ON Abfahrt.id_2 = Wagenuebergaenge.id2
INNER JOIN Ankunft ON Ankunft.id_1 = Wagenuebergaenge.id1
WHERE VT_AB != VT_SB OR
VT_AB = VT_SB And Zeit_AB < Zeit_SE
GROUP BY id_2
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN VT_SE = 'Mo' THEN 1
    WHEN VT_SE = 'Di' THEN 2
    WHEN VT_SE = 'Mi' THEN 3
    WHEN VT_SE = 'Do' THEN 4
    WHEN VT_SE = 'Fr' THEN 5
    WHEN VT_SE = 'Sa' THEN 6
   WHEN VT_SE = 'So' THEN 7
 END, Zeit_SE;
```

This is the full code. My idea was to tell whether the time is greater or less than 1:55, if so, then the day should be changed, if not, only the time should be adjusted. Unfortunately, the code does not work that way.

Does anyone know how to compare times in SqLite? As I said, I can not change the premise of the given data.

```
SELECT id_2, CASE WHEN Zeit_SE > '1:55' THEN VT_SE
                  WHEN ZEIT_SE < '1:55' THEN CASE WHEN VT_SE = 'Mo' THEN VT_SE = 'So' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Di' THEN VT_SE = 'Mo' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Mi' THEN VT_SE = 'Di' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Do' THEN VT_SE = 'Mi' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Fr' THEN VT_SE = 'Do' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'Sa' THEN VT_SE = 'Fr' 
                                WHEN VT_SE = 'So' THEN VT_SE = 'Sa' 
                            END
                  END,
```

Can anyone help me further.

Comment: Store a complete timestamp as a single value in one of the formats understood by sqlite date and time functions (I'd go with either unix epoch time, or a `'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'` formatted string), not just a day and time in separate columns. [Changing your raw input data into something more suitable for your tools to work with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) is a huge part of data processing.

Comment: Hi,
That was also my idea, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following could be the basis for what you want :-

```
/* Cleanup testing environment  */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ergebniss;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS days;

/* Create testing environment */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ergebniss (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tag TEXT, uhrzeit);
INSERT INTO ergebniss (tag,uhrzeit) VALUES 
    ('Mo','00:15'),('Mo','04:15'),('Mo','08:15'),('Mo','12:15'),('Mo','16:15'),('Mo','20:15'),
    ('Di','00:15'),('Di','04:15'),('Di','08:15'),('Di','12:15'),('Di','16:15'),('Di','20:15'),
    /* data to check handling of short values */
    ('Di','0:15'),('Di','4:10'),('Di','8:1'),('Di','12:15'),('Di','16:1'),('Di','20:1') 
;


/* Create Table to allow previous day to be ascertained without CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS days (offset INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,daytext);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO days VALUES (0,'So'),(1,'Mo'),(2,'Di'),(3,'Mi'),(4,'Do'),(5,'Fr'),(6,'Sa');

/* The process time in minutes (1 hour + 55 minutes)*/
WITH 
  /* The process time in minutes (1 hour + 55 minutes) as a CTE*/
    processTime AS (
        SELECT  (1 * 60) + 55
    ),
    /* CTE called withstarttime consisting of all columns from the main table + the starttime */
    withstarttime AS (
        SELECT *, 
            (substr(uhrzeit,1,instr(uhrzeit,':') - 1) * 60 + substr(uhrzeit,instr(uhrzeit,':' + 1))) - (SELECT * FROM processTime) AS smin
        FROM ergebniss
    )

/* get the data from the withstartime CTE calculating the previous day if the starttime is negative */
/* also if negative adjust the time accordingly */
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN smin < 0 THEN
            (SELECT daytext FROM days WHERE offset = 
                (((SELECT offset FROM days WHERE daytext = withstarttime.tag) + 6) % 7))
        ELSE tag 
    END AS stag,
    CASE
        WHEN smin < 0 THEN
            24 * 60 + smin
        ELSE smin
    END AS sminadjusted
FROM withstarttime;

/* Cleanup testing Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ergebniss;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS days;
```

## Result

[image]

- Of course the above assumes 24 hour times, so if your times are not then you would have to find some way of determining AM or PM and adjust the above accordingly.

## Additional

re comment :-

> One last question, iwish to write the query in a insert command. Where
>   must i place the insert into... I get only Syntax Errors

Assuming insert is into a new table e.g. NewEgrebniss (see create) then you could use :-

```
/* Cleanup testing environment  */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ergebniss;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS days;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NewErgebniss;

/* Create testing environment */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ergebniss (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tag TEXT, uhrzeit);
INSERT INTO ergebniss (tag,uhrzeit) VALUES 
    ('Mo','00:15'),('Mo','04:15'),('Mo','08:15'),('Mo','12:15'),('Mo','16:15'),('Mo','20:15'),
    ('Di','00:15'),('Di','04:15'),('Di','08:15'),('Di','12:15'),('Di','16:15'),('Di','20:15'),
    /* data to check handling of short values */
    ('Di','0:15'),('Di','4:10'),('Di','8:1'),('Di','12:15'),('Di','16:1'),('Di','20:1') 
;


/* Create Table to allow previous day to be ascertained without CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS days (offset INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,daytext);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO days VALUES (0,'So'),(1,'Mo'),(2,'Di'),(3,'Mi'),(4,'Do'),(5,'Fr'),(6,'Sa');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NewErgebniss (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tag TEXT, uhrzeit TEXT, start_tag TEXT,  start_uhrzeit INTEGER);

/* The process time in minutes (1 hour + 55 minutes)*/
WITH 
  /* The process time in minutes (1 hour + 55 minutes) as a CTE*/
    processTime AS (
        SELECT  (1 * 60) + 55
    ),
    /* CTE called withstarttime consisting of all columns from the main table + the starttime */
    withstarttime AS (
        SELECT *, 
            (substr(uhrzeit,1,instr(uhrzeit,':') - 1) * 60 + substr(uhrzeit,instr(uhrzeit,':' + 1))) - (SELECT * FROM processTime) AS smin
        FROM ergebniss
    ),
        /* Third CTE for inserting into NewErgebniss table */
        /* get the data from the withstartime CTE calculating the previous day if the starttime is negative */
        /* also if negative adjust the time accordingly */
        insertcte(i_tag,i_uhrzeit,i_stag,i_sminadjusted) AS (
        SELECT tag,uhrzeit,
                CASE 
                        WHEN smin < 0 THEN
                                (SELECT daytext FROM days WHERE offset = 
                                        (((SELECT offset FROM days WHERE daytext = withstarttime.tag) + 6) % 7))
                        ELSE tag 
                END AS stag,
                CASE
                        WHEN smin < 0 THEN
                                24 * 60 + smin
                        ELSE smin
                END AS sminadjusted
        FROM withstarttime 
        )
INSERT INTO NewErgebniss (tag,uhrzeit, start_tag, start_uhrzeit) SELECT * FROM insertcte WHERE 1 = 1
;
/* Display RESULT */
SELECT * FROM NewErgebniss;

/* Cleanup testing Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ergebniss;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS days;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NewErgebniss;
```

This results in :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot,
I just checked the code and it seems this it what i was looking for . Just need only  to modify my own code a bit and it should work.

Comment: @FlorianPichler that's good. If the answer helped you then please tick it as answered.

Comment: One last question, iwish to write the query in a insert command. Where must i place the insert into... I get only Syntax Errors.

Comment: @FlorianPichler this should be asked as a new question, as that is how StackOverflow is meant to work.However, just for this one time only, the answer has been updated. Further questions wil require additional questions being created.